# Clicking a button that will use a broadcast for a modal to appear with data

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, broadcast

On my html page (rollup.html) I have a button that opens a modal.

```
<button id="myBtn" ng-click="printDivModal('rollup-tab')">ModalTest</button>
```

On the js page (rollup.js) here is the code that allows a modal to open upon clicking the button

```
$scope.printDivModal = function(divName) {
            console.log('opening pop up');
            var ModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                //animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'app/views/modals/stackedModal.html',
                size: 'lg',
            });
        }
```

The modal shows what is written in stackedModal.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">The Modal Header</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Text inside the modal.</p>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

I want the button to open the modal using a broadcast to show data from a table.  In stackedModal.js I am trying to accomplish that.  I am creating a controller in the js

```
var app = angular.module('dmdesktop');

app.controller('Rollup', rollUpCtrl);
rollUpCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$uibModal','headersvc','locFiltersvc']
function rollUpCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http, $uibModal, headersvc, locFiltersvc) {

        $rootScope.$broadcast('printerFriendly', service.searchFilter);
        $scope.$on('printerFriendly', function(event, filter){
            $scope.searchFilter = filter;
            $scope.getData();

            $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        });


}
```

It currently just shows the modal with no data.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should resolve the data in your $uibModal.open config's resolve block. You should also specify the controller for the modal you are about to open.
Check out this block of code to see what I'm talking about:

```
templateUrl : 'templates/CustomModal.html',
size: size,
controller: 'YourModalCtrl'
resolve: {
    DataYouNeed: function(SomeDependency) { 
                // this should return a promise
        return SomeDependency.query();
    }
}
```

Then, you should define the 'YourModalCtrl' to inject the 'DataYouNeed' as a dependency. That looks something like this:

```
.controller('YourModalCtrl', function (DataYouNeed) {
    // DataYouNeed will be resolved BEFORE controller initialization
    // thus, your modal will have the data before it opens.
    // add any modal specific logic here.
});
```

It's important to note that modal controller you specify will have an orphaned $scope. In other words, this controller won't have access to data you put on $scope (it has it's own isolate $scope object). Thus, you need to define whatever data your modal needs in the 'resolve' block (shown in the first code snippet).

Comment: Bit confused.  I apologize I am new to this.  So I have to resolve the data in $uibModal instead of inside the stackedModal.js controller?  Should I include the broadcast within the uibModal as well? @HunterBrennick

Comment: Setting your modals config similar to what I did in the first snippet of code will ensure `DataYouNeed` is resolved before `YourModalCtrl` is initialized. In the second snippet of code I'm showing you how to include the resolved data as a dependency into your modal controller (so you can attach it to `$scope` or whatever else you need to do). You'll have the data before the modal opens.